# How to update all column with 0 value to specific value?

Tags: laravel

I want to update all column with 0 value to 1

***Controller***

```
$totalofitem=assets::where('item_name','like','keyboard')
->where('total_cost','like','0')->update(array('total_cost' => '1'));
```

***Got it***

```
$totalofitem=assets::where('item_name','like','keyboard')
->where('total_cost','like','0')->update(['total_cost' => 1]);
```

Comment: Correct your question title

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: fix it just wrong format for my update ty

Comment: @jer so u work it out?

Comment: @TsaiKoga yes ty